# Why when I access an object consisting of three integers, does it subtract from the base pointer, and not the stack pointer?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, assembly, low-level

I wanted to figure out how objects work by looking at the assembly output of the program. I have a class called `Numbers` containing three `ints`.

```
class Numbers {

public:

    int n1;
    int n2;
    int n3;

};
```

Inside the main function, I create an instance named `obj` and set each of the variables to a number.

```
int main() {

    Numbers obj;

    obj.n1 = 1;
    obj.n2 = 2;
    obj.n3 = 3;

}
```

The follwing code is the assembly generated:

```
int main() {
00935240  push        ebp  
00935241  mov         ebp,esp  
00935243  sub         esp,0D8h  
00935249  push        ebx  
0093524A  push        esi  
0093524B  push        edi  
0093524C  lea         edi,[ebp-0D8h]  
00935252  mov         ecx,36h  
00935257  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
0093525C  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
0093525E  mov         eax,dword ptr ds:[0093F000h]  
00935263  xor         eax,ebp  
00935265  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],eax  

    Numbers obj;

    obj.n1 = 1;
00935268  mov         dword ptr [obj],1       ; === Here ===
    obj.n2 = 2;
0093526F  mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],2   ; === Here ===
    obj.n3 = 3;
00935276  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],3   ; === Here ===

    return 0;
0093527D  xor         eax,eax  
}
```

I thought that the base pointer pointed to the top of the stack frame, and since the function is main, pointed to the start of the program. How could it be subtracting from the base pointer when the stack pointer is what is pointing to the current address? Also, why is it accessing the variables out of order. It changes `n1`, then is subtracts 16 bytes to get to the address of `n2`, and then 12 bytes to get to `n3`. Is there any reason for it doing this?

I am using Visual Studio 2013, with MASM as an assembler.

Comment: local variables are below ebp, return address and function args are above ebp.  You can reference stack data from ebp or esp, if you keep track of how esp has been modified since you made the stack frame.  Or, for optimized code, don't even make stack frames.  (default for a while in many compilers).

Comment: Stack grows down as you can also tell from the `sub esp,0D8h`. Since it was saved into `ebp` before that, all the allocated space is at negative offset from `ebp`. `dword ptr [obj]` is misleading, I am pretty sure that's also `ebp`-relative addressing. Using a proper disassembler you should see `ebp-14h` there, so `n1`, `n2` and `n3` are in the expected increasing order.

Comment: Local variables are always allocated on the stack unless they are marked as static.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer : A compiler is free to use any mechanism suitable. Some local variables may appear in registers as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between a wait for a slow Apache Pluto startup and a wait for my boss to finish her call, I like to wander these wasteland of the questions tagged with [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly).
So it is in this bored mood that I write another, useless, answer to this already satisfied OP.

```
;PROLOG

push ebp                    ;Save the caller frame pointer
mov ebp, esp                ;Make our frame pointer 

;ALLOCATE SPACE

sub esp, 0D8h               ;Reserve 216 bytes on the stack 
                            ;Why 216? I dunno, maybe this makes the compiler
                            ;source code easy to write/read/mantain

;SAVE CALLER REGS

push ebx 
push esi 
push edi                    ;Save caller register that we must not clobber

;INIT ALLOCATED SPACE

lea edi, [ebp-0D8h]         ;EDI point to the start (the lower limit) of 
                            ;our reserved space (EDI = EBP-0d8h)

mov ecx, 36h                ;ECX is the number of DWORD to write, 
                            ;36h*4 = 0d8h = 216 bytes

mov eax, 0CCCCCCCCh         ;EAX is the DWORD to write, 0cccccccch comes 
                            ;from the fact that: 1) 0cch is the opcode for 
                            ;int 03h which is by convention the debug exception 
                            ;2) it is easy to spot 3) it is an invalid address to
                            ;deference. This way an uninitialized var will misbehave 
                            ;when used (not for arithmetic). This is for debug purpose.

rep stos dword ptr es:[edi] ;Write ECX times EAX from ES:EDI upward (N.B. UPWARD) 

;SET UP THE CANARY

mov eax, dword ptr ds:[0093F000h]   ;Take a value which is safe in memory and cannot be
                                    ;overwritten by stack overflow (those guys, grrrr...)

xor eax, ebp                        ;Compute a function of the frame pointer and the canary
                                    ;This can make the canary unique on every invocation.
                                    ;The function is a xor 

mov dword ptr [ebp-4],eax           ;The canary is at the very beginning (ending?) or our 
                                    ;allocated space. It is just below the frame pointer.


;Set the object fields                                  

mov dword ptr [obj], 1              ;I believe this obj is [ebp-14h]
mov dword ptr [ebp-10h], 2          ;Remember that [ebp-10h] is after [ebp-14h], just like
mov dword ptr [ebp-0Ch], 3          ;-10 is after (i.e. bigger than)  -14. 


;Return the value 0

xor eax,eax                         ;EAX have to hold the returned value at the end of the 
                                    ;function, V XOR V = 0 for all V
```

Comment: I didn't find this useless, I actually thought it was quite helpful. Thank you for writing this.

Answer (score 3):

The ebp register usually points to the start of the start of the stack frame of the current function (which contains usually the pointer to the previous frame) on the stack.

In the assembly output, first the last stack frame pointer is saved, then the address of the current stack pointer is saved in ebp. This is the start of the stack frame for the current function. Then, some bytes are subtracted from esp to reserve space on the stack for the local variables.

The order of the variables is correct; the variable addresses are below the current ebp address (stack is growing from high to lower addresses).

> I thought that the base pointer pointed to the top of the stack frame,
>   and since the function is main, the start of the program.

`main()` is not really the first function called; there are a lot of libc startup functions called before (e.g. for global object initialization).